# DB Selecting from multiple table with join using alias in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I am trying to do a check against 3 table that I join together. I do not want to use the real table name hard coded as my project is highly under develop and table prefix may be changed. What is the best way in Yii2 to select from 3 table where I have where statement on the joined table?
I can get what I want from the code below. But as I said, I do not want to use the table alias hard coded. Any idea how to fix this or suggestion of other ideas would be very appreciated.

```
 $userId = Yii::$app->user->id;
  $result = \app\models\UserPermission::find()->joinWith([ 
      'permission',
      'permission.service'
    ])->where([
      'prefix_user_permission.user_id' => $userId,
      'prefix_permission.flag' => Permission::LOGIN,
      'prefix_service.login_available' => Service::LOGIN_AVAIABLE,
    ])->all();
```

I would like to end up with this query:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM `prefix_user_permission` `up`
  INNER JOIN `prefix_permission` `p` ON `up`.`permission_id` = `p`.`id`
  INNER JOIN `prefix_service` `s` ON `p`.`service_id` = `s`.`id`
  WHERE (`up`.`user_id`=43)
    AND (`p`.`flag`='LOGIN')
    AND (`s`.`login_available`=1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table prefix can be configured using the 'tablePrefix' param along with the main db config as follows:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        //other db config params
        'tablePrefix' => 'pre_'
    ]
```

This prefix can be used as follows:

> There's a special variant on this syntax specific to tablenames: {{%Y}} automatically appends the application's table prefix to the provided value, if a table prefix has been set:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT([[$column]]) FROM {{%table}}";
$rowCount = $connection->createCommand($sql)->queryScalar();
```

Or if you are using active record for models then you can also use the tableName() function to replace the hard-coded table names.